# Solr does not highlight some words

Tags: solr, highlight

I configured solr 4.10 (also 5.3) with [highlighting functionality](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters). It works fine with most of the words, however I found some words which "**does not**" allow highlightings, that is, solr returns the required docs, but does not highlights some of them.

What can cause such effect?

**solrconfig.xml**

```
 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="wt">json</str>
   <str name="indent">true</str>
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="bf">product(concount)</str>
   <str name="df">text bio text_syn text_syn_other</str>
   <str name="qf">
    text^25 bio^16 text_syn^8 text_syn_other^3
   </str>
   <str name="hl">on</str>
   <str name="hl.fl">text bio text_syn text_syn_other</str>
   <str name="hl.preserveMulti">true</str>
   <str name="hl.encoder">html</str>
   <str name="f.text.hl.fragsize">100</str>
   <str name="hl.snippets">20</str>
   <arr name="components">
     <str>highlight</str>
   </arr>
 </lst>
```

**schema.xml**

```
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\n,/\\]" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_abbr.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\n,/\\]" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_en_syn" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\n,/\\]" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\n,/\\]" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_en_syn_other" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\n,/\\]" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_other.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\n,/\\]" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="text_syn" type="text_en_syn" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="text_syn_other" type="text_en_syn_other" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

<field name="text_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />

<field name="bio" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

<field name="bio_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />

<field name="concount" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

<field name="concount_exact" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />

<copyField source="text" dest="text_syn"/>
<copyField source="bio" dest="text_syn"/>
<copyField source="text" dest="text_syn_other"/>
<copyField source="bio" dest="text_syn_other"/>
```

For the query `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=senior` I got docs containing the word `senior`, but in highlighting section of solr response that word is not highlighted.

---

**UPDATE 1:**
I find out that I have the word `senior` in my `synonyms_abbr.txt` file, the line `senior,lead`. When I commented that line or replaced the places of words, `lead,senior`, surprisingly the word `senior` started geting highlighting. Any ideas ?

---

**UPDATE 2:**
Words from `synonyms.txt` and `synonyms_other.txt` are getting highlighting normally, but words from `synonyms_abbr.txt` behave strangely as follows. For example, I have the line `lead,head,senior` in `synonyms_abbr.txt` then

- the queries `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=senior` and `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=head` does not highlight any word,
- the query `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=lead` highlights not only the word `lead`, but also `head` and `senior`.

Comment: Please use the Solr backend functionality for an analysis of the transformation of the word. I'm not sure about the way the word is transformed. It could be a stemming issue. Otherwise, use a different field, switch off the transformations leaving only the tokenizer, then try highlighting from that field.

Comment: @Mher Are the words that do not get highlighted stop words? Or just random?

Comment: I don't have any stopwords configures. The whole `stopwords.txt` file is commented.

Comment: Did you try with `expand=true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your update2 it is clear that only the first word among `lead,head,senior` is actually used for synonym matching and highlighting.

If you look at Docs on SolrWiki https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters there is a mention of `expand=true` having a certain effect

*The synonyms parameter names an external file defining the synonyms.
If ignoreCase is true, matching will lowercase before checking equality.
**If expand is true, a synonym will be expanded to all equivalent synonyms. If it is false, all equivalent synonyms will be reduced to the first in the list**.*

The site also presents and example

```
# If expand==true, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent to the explicit mapping:
ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod, i-pod, i pod
# If expand==false, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent to the explicit mapping:
ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod
```

This seems to be consistent with the behaviour you are observing. 
This implies that you should change the Synonym filters definition in schema.xml to use expand=true OR 
change the way your synonyms file defines the filter to use explicit mapping.

Additionally since the Analyzers work at time of indexing, you may have to reindex documents for this to work.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it's very helpful, can you please explain the other part of a question: it is, for example we have `expand=true`, why when I query synonym-word from the `synonyms_abbr.txt` file then all synonyms of that word are getting highlight as well as itself, however wehen choose synonym from `synonyms.txt` then highlighting gets only that word, not the synonyms of that word ?

Comment: Looking at your field definition, it appears that fields linked to synonym.txt are configured with store=false. Therefore highlighting won't work. See the other response to this question from ilinca

Answer (score 2):

Some fields are not stored thus cannot be returned. Since they are indexed they are searchable. Change your schema to have stored="true" for all the fields you want to highlight.

```
<field name="text_syn" type="text_en_syn" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="text_syn_other" type="text_en_syn_other" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

By looking at your config I presume highlighting works on the fields bio and text?

Comment: no @linca, highlighting does not work just on the fields bio and text. I am not considering the fileds that are not stored.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The line <str name="hl.fl">text bio text_syn text_syn_other</str> made me think you want highlights on the 2 unstored fields too. I think we'll need an example of the fields' values, query, result.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add senior,lead and lead,senior to the file synonyms_abbr.txt and then try to run the highlighter